# How to make it so an image disappears upon collision and then re-appears in a random spot on the screen

Tags: java, processing

I'm creating a game similar to Snake in which my Batman character image collides with the Joker character image and "catches" it. Once the first one disappears, another Joker pops up on the screen in a random spot for the Batman to chase after and then so and so forth.

I've made it so the first Joker disappears when my Batman character collides with it but I'm struggling to get a second Joker to pop on the screen. I'm not sure if a for loop would be best - but then how do I make it so only one Joker appears until Batman "catches" it and then the next can appear - or perhaps an if statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm feeling really stuck right now.

```
//loads music for background

import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile file;

String audioName = "dark_knight_rises.wav";

String path;

//loads gif library for background

import gifAnimation.*;

Gif myAnimation;

PImage batman;       //pixel images

PImage joker;        //pixel images

int batmanX = 100;        //batman X position on screen

int batmanY = 100;        //batman Y position on screen

int jokerX = 500;         //joker X position on screen

int jokerY = 500;         //joker Y position on screen

int batman1Size = 50;     //for batman distance

int joker2Size = 50;      //for joker distance

int width = 100;          //width for characters

int height = 100;         // height for characters

boolean showImage = true; // boolean to help joker disappear and reappear

int score = 0;            // declaration for high score




void setup() {

  size(1067, 800);

  //plays background music

  path = sketchPath(audioName);

  file = new SoundFile(this, path);

  file.play();

  //loads background and pixel-style batman/joker

  myAnimation = new Gif(this, "background.gif");

  myAnimation.play();

  batman = loadImage("pixelbatman.png");

  joker = loadImage("pixeljoker.png");
}

void draw() {

  image(myAnimation, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background 

  //display the score

  textSize(20);

  text("Jokers caught:", 900, 40);

  text(score, 1045, 40);


  image(batman, batmanX, batmanY, width, height);   //places Batman character on screen

  //pixel batman movement

  if (keyPressed) {

    if (key == CODED) {

      if (keyCode == UP) batmanY--;

      if (keyCode == RIGHT) batmanX++;

      if (keyCode == DOWN) batmanY++;

      if (keyCode == LEFT) batmanX--;

    }
  }    //end of pixel batman movement


  if (showImage) image(joker, jokerX, jokerY, width, height);   //if Boolean is true, place Joker character on screen

  if (dist(batmanX, batmanY, jokerX, jokerY) < (batman1Size + joker2Size)/10 ) { //if batman and joker collide - joker disappears

    showImage = false;

    score += 1; //increase the score by 1 when batman eats a joker


    // idea is that the first joker disappears and another pops up in a random position

    if (showImage == false) {

      image(joker, random(jokerX, 0), random(0, jokerY), width, height);

    }

  } // end of what happens if batman and joker collide

} // end of void draw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easier than you think. In fact, you already did most of the job, you just need a rubber duck.

I'll take that job.

In the `draw()` function, you do a lot of things. When you have free time, I suggest you break these down a little bit. `draw()` is the main loop in processing, and as such it'll always tend to be clogged with code. When you do this, aim to have an easily understandable loop, something like this:

```
void draw() {
  drawBackground();
  manageInput();
  collisions();
  drawCharacters();
}
```

Now, to the matter which interests you:

What you're doing good:

- you use clear nomenclature (your naming convention makes things easy to read, a mistake beginners do is to shorten variables names because they know what they are speaking about, then it confuses everybody else including themselves later on)
- great job overall with being able to add stuff like gif and sounds!

What we're going to do to achieve the joker thing:

1. Get rid of the `showImage` variable. I get what you're doing here, and it was a good idea, but we won't need it.
2. In the `If` where you check for a collision, right where you wrote `showImage = false`, instead we'll update the joker's coordinates:

Like this (I randomized it, but now that you get the idea you can custom this):

```
jokerX = (int)random(width);
jokerY = (int)random(height);
```

3. Delete the `if (showImage == false)`.

Aaand... there you go! If you read well, you'll notice that your mistake wat that, in the `if (showImage == false)` part, you "teleported" the joker without actually changing his coordinated.

I'll stick around in case you have questions. Have fun!

Comment: Wow, thank you thank you thank you! The one question I do have is that now my Joker teleports to the upper left-hand corner of the screen and tends to stay in that one area every time Batman captures it. I tried fiddling with the randomized Joker coordinates code but it still keeps staying in that relative corner.

Comment: Current code:

if (dist(batmanX, batmanY, jokerX, jokerY) < (batman1Size + joker2Size)/10 ) { 

//if batman and joker collide - joker disappears and another pops up in a random position

    jokerX = (int)random(width++);  //randomized Joker's X coordinates
    jokerY = (int)random(height++);  //randomized Joker's Y coordinates
    score += 1; //increase the score by 1 when batman captures a joker

   
  } // end of what happens if batman and joker collide

Comment: @Jada-1 That's my fault, I hadn't noticed that you already had globals named `width` and `height`. [Here's how `random` works.](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) Instead of variables, use the min and max number where the joker can appear on the X and Y axis, and you're golden. Also, the `++` add 1 to the variable everytime you loop, which wouldn't help much here but somehow might make it look like it does. Unless it was deliberate, you might want to avoid the `++` there.

Comment: Got it - its working now, thank you again for all your help!